# Restructuring a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
A7  A8  A9  A10 A11 A12 B7  B8  B9  B10 B11 B12
A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18 B13 B14 B15 B16 B17 B18
A19 A20 A21 A22 A23 A24 B19 B20 B21 B22 B23 B24
A25 A26 A27 A28 A29 A30 B25 B26 B27 B28 B29 B30
A31 A32 A33 A34 A35 A36 B31 B32 B33 B34 B35 B36
A37 A38 A39 A40 A41 A42 B37 B38 B39 B40 B41 B42
A43 A44 A45 A46 A47 A48 B43 B44 B45 B46 B47 B48
A49 A50 A51 A52 A53 A54 B49 B50 B51 B52 B53 B54
A55 A56 A57 A58 A59 A60 B55 B56 B57 B58 B59 B60
A61 A62 A63 A64 A65 A66 B61 B62 B63 B64 B65 B66
A67 A68 A69 A70 A71 A72 B67 B68 B69 B70 B71 B72
A73 A74 A75 A76 A77 A78 B73 B74 B75 B76 B77 B78
A79 A80 A81 A82 A83 A84 B79 B80 B81 B82 B83 B84
A85 A86 A87 A88 A89 A90 B85 B86 B87 B88 B89 B90
A91 A92 A93 A94 A95 A96 B91 B92 B93 B94 B95 B96
```

The dataset is only 16 rows long, but has hundreds of columns.  Meaningful chunks are always 6 columns wide.  I would like to restructure the data frame so that it looks like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18 A19 A20 A21 A22 A23 A24 A25 A26 A27 A28 A29 A30 A31 A32 A33 A34 A35 A36 A37 A38 A39 A40 A41 A42 A43 A44 A45 A46 A47 A48 A49 A50 A51 A52 A53 A54 A55 A56 A57 A58 A59 A60 A61 A62 A63 A64 A65 A66 A67 A68 A69 A70 A71 A72 A73 A74 A75 A76 A77 A78 A79 A80 A81 A82 A83 A84 A85 A86 A87 A88 A89 A90 A91 A92 A93 A94 A95 A96
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10 B11 B12 B13 B14 B15 B16 B17 B18 B19 B20 B21 B22 B23 B24 B25 B26 B27 B28 B29 B30 B31 B32 B33 B34 B35 B36 B37 B38 B39 B40 B41 B42 B43 B44 B45 B46 B47 B48 B49 B50 B51 B52 B53 B54 B55 B56 B57 B58 B59 B60 B61 B62 B63 B64 B65 B66 B67 B68 B69 B70 B71 B72 B73 B74 B75 B76 B77 B78 B79 B80 B81 B82 B83 B84 B85 B86 B87 B88 B89 B90 B91 B92 B93 B94 B95 B96
```

Ideally, the finished product will be 96 columns wide, with a single row for each "meaningful chunk" of data.

Any/all suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You should post a better description of the original. Specify the result of `dim(dfrmname)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose to 1) turn your data into a three dimensional array 2) permute dimensions 3) revert to a two dimensional array:

```
a  <- as.matrix(df)
n1 <- nrow(a)
n2 <- ncol(a)
dim(a) <- c(n1, 6, n2 / 6)
a <- aperm(a, c(3, 2, 1))
dim(a) <- c(n2 / 6, 6 * n1)
```

Comment: You have my upvote but you will increase my already substantial respect for your skills if you can expand on the thinking that lets you decide how to permute the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. Honestly, I had to try a few before I came up with c(3, 2, 1). I knew it had to work one way or the other. I'm terrible at the rubik's cube.

Comment: Oh, you mean I'm not the only one who tries ten variations to come up with one good answer?

Comment: Come to think about it, `3` needed to come first because we want the `n2/6` chunks (dim 3) to become the rows (dim 1). Then, dimensions 1 and 2 also had to be transposed because the data in each chunk is not oriented in the natural column-wise R fashion. Hence c(3, 2, 1).

Answer (score 2):

One method:

```
rbind( c ( t ( dfrm[1:6])),  # t will  turn rows into columns of matrix
       c ( t ( dfrm[7:12])) ) # c() will concatenate the columns
```

Depending on what you want to do with this, may need to wrap `as.data.frame` around the result because it will return a matrix.

The example was solved and now a more general solution is requested:

```
t( sapply(seq(1, length(dfrm), by=6), function(n) c(t(dfrm[n:(n+5)])) ) )
#---

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5" "A6" "A7" "A8" "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12" "A13"
[2,] "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" "B8" "B9" "B10" "B11" "B12" "B13"
     [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
[1,] "A14" "A15" "A16" "A17" "A18" "A19" "A20" "A21" "A22" "A23" "A24" "A25"
[2,] "B14" "B15" "B16" "B17" "B18" "B19" "B20" "B21" "B22" "B23" "B24" "B25"
     [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37]
[1,] "A26" "A27" "A28" "A29" "A30" "A31" "A32" "A33" "A34" "A35" "A36" "A37"
[2,] "B26" "B27" "B28" "B29" "B30" "B31" "B32" "B33" "B34" "B35" "B36" "B37"
     [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49]
[1,] "A38" "A39" "A40" "A41" "A42" "A43" "A44" "A45" "A46" "A47" "A48" "A49"
[2,] "B38" "B39" "B40" "B41" "B42" "B43" "B44" "B45" "B46" "B47" "B48" "B49"
     [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61]
[1,] "A50" "A51" "A52" "A53" "A54" "A55" "A56" "A57" "A58" "A59" "A60" "A61"
[2,] "B50" "B51" "B52" "B53" "B54" "B55" "B56" "B57" "B58" "B59" "B60" "B61"
     [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73]
[1,] "A62" "A63" "A64" "A65" "A66" "A67" "A68" "A69" "A70" "A71" "A72" "A73"
[2,] "B62" "B63" "B64" "B65" "B66" "B67" "B68" "B69" "B70" "B71" "B72" "B73"
     [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85]
[1,] "A74" "A75" "A76" "A77" "A78" "A79" "A80" "A81" "A82" "A83" "A84" "A85"
[2,] "B74" "B75" "B76" "B77" "B78" "B79" "B80" "B81" "B82" "B83" "B84" "B85"
     [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96]
[1,] "A86" "A87" "A88" "A89" "A90" "A91" "A92" "A93" "A94" "A95" "A96"
[2,] "B86" "B87" "B88" "B89" "B90" "B91" "B92" "B93" "B94" "B95" "B96"
```

Comment: Indeed. I originally wrote c() and then changed it to unlist() and now it's back to c().

Comment: For some reason I thought `t()` was going to return a dataframe. Foolish me.

Comment: My actual data frame is hundreds of columns long.  It has many of these 6-column-wide chunks.  I tried your code but it didn't work.  Is it because your code is specific to the example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure mine is more beautiful. Basically the same logic.